# Search Text and Replace with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

Example I've this code:

```
<div class="description"> I make you smile. </div>
```

Transformed to:

```
<div class="description"> I make you think. </div>
```

Note: "smile" was replaced to "think"

How can I replace it, using javascript jQuery? It's possible to change several words?

Comment: question shows a lack of prior search efort... likely 100's of similar posts here already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ele = $("div.description");                     //Let ele be target element
ele.html(ele.html().replace(/smile/gi,"think"));    //Replace the word in string,
                                                    // then put it back in.
```

*`.replace`*: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/FdyEH/